# Unable to load static resources:Spring MVC

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, css, spring-mvc

I am creating a sample application with Spring MVC.My problem is that my static resources like css and javascript are not loaded.Could anyone please help me.This is my first spring application.Any help will be highly appreciable....

Below are my code...

login.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

<html>

<head>

<spring:url value="/resources/common/css/login.css" var="loginCSS" />
<spring:url value="/resources/common/js/login.js" var="loginJS" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="${loginCSS}" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="${loginJS}"></script>

</head>

<body>

<h2>Sample spring mvc</h2>
<div class="test">
  <div class="form">

    <form class="test">
      <input type="text" placeholder="username"/>
      <input type="password" placeholder="password"/>
      <button>login</button>
      <p class="message">Not registered? <a href="#">Create an account</a></p>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

sample-servlet

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.sample.controller" />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />

    </bean>
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
    <!-- <mvc:default-servlet-handler/> -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

</beans>
```

login.css

```
.test {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Myfolder structure
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />` with

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/css/**" location="/resources/common/css/" />        
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/js/**" location="/resources/common/js/" />
```

And in your jsp use like this:

```
<spring:url value="/resources/css/login.css" var="loginCSS" />
<spring:url value="/resources/js/login.js" var="loginJS" />
```

Comment: i tried this,but it still not loading the resources

Comment: Share your directory structure

Comment: I added my folder structure to my question

Comment: Move your resources folder outside WEB-INF, inside WebContent